# How to specify a vector valued function from one-dimension to one-dimension?

Tags: vectors

I am not sure how I can specify this. I know that $\mathbb{R}^2$ specifies the set of all two-dimensional vectors, so that must mean that $\mathbb{R}$ specifies all one-dimensional vectors. However, of course this also specifies all real numbers! Thus, I am not sure how to specify a mapping from the set of all 1D vectors to 1D vectors since it would essentially look like a mapping from real numbers to real numbers.

Comment: The only thing, perhaps, is that if you are mapping vectors to vectors, then you are probably looking for mappings that are linear transformations from the one-dimensional vector space over the real numbers to itself. These necessarily take the forms of lines through the origin.

Comment: Vectors are not vectors because they live in n copies of the real numbers but because of their behavior under coordinate transformations. I don't see you using that anywhere.

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math question?

Comment: 1. This seems to be a pure math question. 2. Why is it a problem that "1D vectors look like real numbers"?

Answer (score 1):

"...it would essentially look like a mapping from real numbers to real numbers"

Yes, it would. All vectors spaces of dimension $n$ are isomorphic. Since there can only be one linearly independent vector in a 1D vector space, a 1D vector is described by a single real number, say $\lambda$. Mappings between this 1D vector space and a different 1D vector space are just mappings from real numbers to real numbers, changing the value of $\lambda $ assigned to each 1D vector.